# Mysqli num rows shows 0 result

Tags: mysql

I'm having two queries which I fetch to return max voted up and max voted down, but the first query returns 0 result and the second return some results indeed I have quad checked my results in database but the first return 0. I have spent much time debugging this but I didn't come to any result. Maybe one eye can't find it so I wanted to share this with you then much eyes can find it maybe or ? :) .

My first code of Top up votes query --------> returns 0

```
SELECT m.id ,cm.id ,cm.userid,cm.replyto,m.username ,cm.message,cm.edited,cm.date,cm.voteup,cm.votedown  
FROM chat_messages cm  
INNER JOIN members m  ON m.id =cm.userid
WHERE  cm.voteup - cm.votedown = (SELECT MAX(voteup - votedown ) 
                                  FROM chat_messages 
                                  WHERE  deleted != 1 
                                  AND voteup - votedown >= 5   ) 
AND  cm.room_id = 1      
ORDER BY cm.votedown asc,cm.voteup DESC,cm.id  
LIMIT 1
```

--------> this gives me 0

and my second Top down votes query--------> works; I'm getting result

```
 SELECT m.id ,cm.id ,cm.userid,cm.replyto,m.username ,cm.message,cm.edited,cm.date,cm.voteup,cm.votedown  
 FROM chat_messages cm  
 INNER JOIN members m  ON m.id =cm.userid
 WHERE  cm.votedown - cm.voteup = (SELECT MAX(votedown - voteup)
                                   FROM chat_messages 
                                   WHERE deleted != 1 
                                   AND votedown - voteup >= 5) 
 AND  cm.room_id = 1  
 ORDER BY cm.voteup ASC, cm.votedown DESC, cm.id 
 LIMIT 1
```

Any one have any idea ?

**EDIT:**

I'm getting result if `voteup - votedown >= 7` And here where I'm getting foul , because in my query I have >=5 so I wonder why ?

**EDIT2:**

My database schema

```
  id    int(11) AUTO_INCREMENT  
  userid    int(11) 
  replyto   int(11)
  message   text    utf8_general_ci 
  room_id   int(11) 
  edited    text    utf8_general_ci
  deleted   int(1)
  date  datetime
  date_edited   datetime
  voteup    int(11)
  votedown  int(11)
```

Comment: can you post your database schema. It will be useful.

Comment: @KajaMydeen please look my edit if it helps

Comment: @KajaMydeen added database schema , thanks .

Comment: Consult these following links http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php
and apply that to your code. We've no way to know if your variables have values.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Dear sir  i have edited my question, maybe you think its about the variables or php , i have the problem in my query . i have tested in my mysql host and it gives nothing despite i have values that are greater then 5 .  and my second works